# Variable getting via Ajax is empty ( Phonegap-Ajax-Json-PHP-MySQL )

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, cordova

I created an android application using Phonegap. I made an account in [000webhost](http://000webhost.com) and I've added my `PHP` files on the server. In the phpMyAdmin, I've created my database.

Right, now I tried to connect my project with the online database and insert or check some data in it.

---

**PROBLEM**:

1. When I run the application in my mobile phone i get this alert from the `success: ...` part of code in ajax : 
   `There is no such username`. 
    
   (my PHP had in comments all the `echo`, except the: `echo json_encode`)
2. When I added this line (`var_dump($_POST);`) right after i am getting the `$username`from ajax in the PHP and run my app, I saw this alert: 
   `array(1){ [\"username\"]=> string(2) \"hi"\" }`
3. When I added these lines: `if (empty($username)) { echo '...' }` , after I run my app, I saw that in the alert inside the `error: ...` part of the ajax, it is printed the `echo` that is inside this `if`. So, the `$username` is empty for sure.

---

This is my `JavaScript` file: 
(I get correctly for sure all the values from `html` so Focus on the two Ajax parts of code)

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var el = document.getElementById("register"); 
        el.addEventListener("click", Register, false); 
    }

function Register() {
  var username = document.getElementsByName('username')[0];
  var password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0];
  var email = document.getElementsByName('email')[0];

  var strong_flag_user = 0;
  var user = username.value; 

  if (username.value == "") {
    $("#username").focus();
    document.getElementById('username').style.boxShadow = "0 0 7px #f00";
    navigator.notification.vibrate(500);
  } 
  else{
    $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.guidemeforall.freeiz.com/phps/check_for_dublicates/check_username.php",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: { username: user },
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(response){ 
                if (response.status == 'success') { 
                    alert(response.message);
                    document.getElementById('username').style.boxShadow = "none";
                    strong_flag_user = 1;
                } 
                else if (response.status == 'error') { 
                    alert(response.message);
                    navigator.notification.alert("This username is already taken! Please use another one!", null, 'Username', 'Okay');
                    document.getElementById('username').style.boxShadow = "0 0 7px #f00";
                    navigator.notification.vibrate(500);
                    strong_flag_user = 0;
                    //window.location("main.html");
                }
                else { 
                  alert("error");                     
                  strong_flag_user = 0;
                }
            },
            error: function(error){ //function(error){
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                strong_flag_user = 0;
                //window.location = "main.html";
            }
    });
  }

   //>5 characters, 1 upper case, at least 1 lower case, at least 1 numerical character, at least 1 special character
   var passExp = /(?=^.{6,15}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*/;
   var strong_flag_pass = 0;

  if (!(password.value.match(passExp))) {
    $("#password").focus();
    document.getElementById('password').style.boxShadow = "0 0 7px #f00";
    navigator.notification.alert("Please enter a strong Password! It has to have at least: 6 characters, 1 upper case, 1 lower case, 1 numerical character and 1 special character!", null, 'Password', 'Okay');
    navigator.notification.vibrate(500);
    strong_flag_pass = 0;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('password').style.boxShadow = "none";
    strong_flag_pass = 1;
  }

  var emailExp = /^.+@[^\.].*\.[a-z]{2,}$/;
  var strong_flag_email = 0;

  if (!(email.value.match(emailExp))) {
    $("#email").focus();
    document.getElementById('email').style.boxShadow = "0 0 7px #f00";
    navigator.notification.alert("Please enter a correct Email!", null, 'Email', 'Okay');
    navigator.notification.vibrate(500);
    strong_flag_email = 0;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('email').style.boxShadow = "none";
    strong_flag_email = 1;
  }

  var gender;
  if (document.getElementById("gender").value == "female")
    gender = 'F';
  else
    gender = 'M';

  var about_you = document.getElementById("about_you").value;

  var age = document.getElementById("radio-choice").value;

  if (document.getElementById('radio-choice-1').checked) {
    age = document.getElementById('radio-choice-1').value;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('radio-choice-2').checked) {
    age = document.getElementById('radio-choice-2').value;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('radio-choice-3').checked) {
    age = document.getElementById('radio-choice-3').value;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('radio-choice-4').checked) {
    age = document.getElementById('radio-choice-4').value;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('radio-choice-5').checked) {
    age = document.getElementById('radio-choice-5').value;
  }

  else if (document.getElementById('radio-choice-6').checked) {
    age = document.getElementById('radio-choice-6').value;
  }

  if (strong_flag_user == 1 && strong_flag_pass == 1 && strong_flag_email == 1){      
    //add to db
    register_db(email.value, password.value, username.value, gender, about_you, age);
  }
}

function register_db(em, pass, user, gend, about, ag) {
    $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.guidemeforall.freeiz.com/phps/sign-up.php",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: { username:user, password:pass, email:em, gender:gend, about_you:about, age:ag },
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data.status == 'success')
                {
                      alert("Success!");
                }
                else if (data.status == 'error')
                {
                      alert("Failure!");
                }
            }
   });
}
```

---

This is my `PHP` file in which I check if the username already exists (Username = Primary Key):

```
 <?php 

      header('Content-type: application/json'); 
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

      //require_once('../database_config.php');

      $server = "my***.000webhost.com";
      $database = "a1****37_guideme";
      $username = "a1****37_guideme";
      $password = "*****";

      $con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);

      // if($con) { //echo "Connected to database!"; }
      // else { //echo "Could not connect!"; }

      mysql_select_db($database, $con);

      $topost = file_get_contents('php://input');

      $thedata = json_decode($topost, true);

      $username = $thedata['username'];
      //var_dump($_POST);

      //if (empty($username)) {
      //     echo 'The username is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
      //}

      $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as Count FROM `user` WHERE `username`='$username'";

      $result= mysql_query($sql, $con);

      $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

      $count = $rows['Count'];

      if (!$result) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        //$response_array['status'] = 'error';  
        //echo json_encode($response_array);
      } 
      else {
        if ($count == 0) {
          echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success','message'=> 'There is no such username'));
          //$response_array['status'] = 'success';  
          //echo json_encode($response_array);
        }
        else
        {
          echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message'=> 'The username already exists'));
          //$response_array['status'] = 'error';  
          //echo json_encode($response_array); 
        }
      }

      mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

---

And this is the `PHP` file in which I tried to insert the new entry in my database ( my credentials are for sure correct):

```
<?php 

  header('Content-type: application/json');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

  //require_once('database_config.php');

  $server = "mys****.000webhost.com";
  $database = "a***37_guideme";
  $username = "a***37_guideme";
  $password = "******";

  $con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);

  // if($con) { //echo "Connected to database!"; }
  // else { //echo "Could not connect!"; }

  mysql_select_db($database, $con);

  $topost = file_get_contents('php://input');

  $thedata = json_decode($topost, true);

  $username = $thedata['username'];
  $password = $thedata['password'];
  $email = $thedata['email'];
  $gender = $thedata['gender'];
  $age = $thedata['age'];
  $about_you = $thedata['about_you'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password, email, gender, age, about_you) ";
  $sql .= "VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$gender', '$age', '$about_you')";

  if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      // $response_array['status'] = 'error';  
      // echo json_encode($response_array);
  } 
  else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success','message'=> 'No problem'));
    // $response_array['status'] = 'success';  
    // echo json_encode($response_array);
  }

  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

---

Comment: instead of `alert`, try `console.log(error)` and see the object in the console window.

Comment: or alert(JSON.stringify(error));

Comment: @itachi, about the `console.log(error)`where do I can see it's output ?
@jcesarmobile I will try it

Comment: if you are using chrome, hit `F12` and check the console tab.

Comment: About that, i may sound a bit stupid but in the server I added only my php files so i can't run my app from chrome.. It's better to add my whole project in the web host server so that i can check it via chrome?

Comment: I updated my question with the new error and the new line of code in `error: ...` that I added after @jcesarmobile suggestion.

Comment: the response is ok, so if you get the error callback the json shouldn't be ok, remove the datatype: "json" from the ajax call or create a propper json response

Comment: @jcesarmobile I removed from both .ajax codes the datatype:"json" but the error remains the same so I just put it back but isntead of `datatype` i wrote `dataType`. About the second one I am not really sure what I have to do. Related to the message that is being alerted, I don't think it's an error what is being printed. I just don't know why it goes to the `error: ...` instead of `success: ...` Also, i discovered as you can see in my updated question that for some reason, the `$username` variable in php is empty, so it doesn't take correctly the value from JavaScript.

Comment: If you put de datatype JSON, the response expect a JSON, but you are returning a regular string 'Connected to database!username::{"status":"error","message":"The username already exists"}'. Remove everything that isn't JSON

Comment: I did what you asked and now the alert is from `success: ..` part of ajax. The `username` var in PHP, is empty, it doesn't get the value from JavaScript, so every time i run my application it says that: `there is no such username`. Also, after that message, nothing is being printed or saved in SQL as it should be according to my code.

Comment: And are you sure the username is being sent?

Comment: Well I am not sure but this is the way I found on the internet.... But i am quite sure it's empty because it goes and print the echo inside the if the username is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved by changing the way I get the data in my PHP to -> `$user = $_POST['username'];` instead of the way with Json (`json_decode` e.t.c.).